# Encountering Error 500 in LinkedIn API Requests

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I'm encountering an issue while making requests to the LinkedIn API. I'm consistently receiving an "Internal Server Error" (Error Code: 500) when executing the following request:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAnalytics?q=statistics&pivots=List(ACCOUNT)&dateRange=(start:(year:2023,month:1,day:1),end:(year:2023,month:12,day:31))&timeGranularity=MONTHLY&accounts=List(urn:li:sponsoredAccount:3A502840441)&fields=impressions,clicks,costInLocalCurrency,externalWebsiteConversions&sortBy.field=IMPRESSIONS&sortBy.order=DESCENDING
```

This error occurs consistently and is impacting my API integration. I have reviewed the request code, checked for formatting errors or missing parameters, but I cannot pinpoint the root cause of this error.

I've attempted several variations of the request URL by adjusting date ranges, removing certain parameters, and double-checking the syntax for accuracy. Initially, I expected to receive the analytics data corresponding to the specified date range and account. However, despite these attempts and ensuring proper formatting, I consistently received an "Internal Server Error" (Error Code: 500) in response.

I was expecting a successful response with the requested analytics data, but unfortunately, I kept encountering the Error 500 without any additional insights into the root cause of the issue.

I'm curious if anyone in the community has encountered this issue before or if there's a specific guideline I might be overlooking while making this request.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve this error. Thank you for your help!